# SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Type de colonne non valide: 1111

Tags: spring, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, plsql

I have this call to PL/SQL function

```
FUNCTION F_IsDemandeDeLitFromHosp(i_NoMvtHosp   IN MVTHOSP.NOMVTHOSP%TYPE  
)RETURN BOOLEAN
IS
   v_Found NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   BEGIN
      SELECT COUNT(1) INTO v_Found
        FROM ICSF.T_DEMANDE_LIT D, MVTUS U, MVTHOSP H
       WHERE H.NOMVTHOSP = i_NoMvtHosp
         AND H.NOMVTHOSP = U.NOMVTHOSP
         AND U.NOMVTUS = D.NOMVTUS
         AND U.RANG <> '0000000000'
         AND H.RANG = '0000100000'
         AND NVL (D.ETAT, ' ') <> 'X'
         AND NVL (U.ETAT, ' ') <> 'X'
         AND NVL (H.ETAT, ' ') <> 'X'
         AND ROWNUM = 1;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         RETURN FALSE;
   END;
   IF v_Found > 0 THEN
      RETURN TRUE;
   ELSE
      RETURN FALSE;
   END IF;
END F_IsDemandeDeLitFromHosp;
```

I try to write a service to get the boolean in return. `i_NoMvtHosp` is a `CHAR(10 BYTE)` and here is the call of my function:

```
@Override
public DemandeDeLitFromHospit isDemandeDelitFromHosp(String noMvtHosp) {
    final ProcedureRequest request = new ProcedureRequest(PK.GET_IS_DEMANDE_DE_LIT_FROM_HOSP.getPackageName(), PK.GET_IS_DEMANDE_DE_LIT_FROM_HOSP.getMethodeName());
    request.addInParam("i_NoMvtHosp", noMvtHosp);
    DemandeDeLitFromHospit demande = new DemandeDeLitFromHospit();
    demande.setIsDemandeDeLitFromHosp((Boolean)callFunction(request, new CallableStatementCallback<Boolean>() {

        public Boolean doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            cs.execute();
            return Boolean.valueOf(cs.getResultSet().toString());
        }
    }));
    return demande;
}
```

And I've got this error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Type de colonne non valide: 1111; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Type de colonne non valide: 1111
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1032)
    at fr.mckesson.framework.persistence.plsql.AbstractProcedureDao.callFunction(AbstractProcedureDao.java:317)
    at fr.mckesson.business.venue.clinique.evenement.dao.implementation.DemandeLitDAO.isDemandeDelitFromHosp(DemandeLitDAO.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Where am i wrong ?

Comment: Type 1111 is `java.sql.Types.OTHER`, something is going wrong with type inference somewhere. Also I strongly suggest that you set your locale config so you get English error messages. It makes it easier to search for similar problems (and is probably a lot clearer for people reading your question).

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the body of your `AbstractProcedureDao.callFunction` method?  I don't see where in your Java code you are specifying the type of object returned by the function.  (Incidentally, I don't believe that `cs.getResultSet()` in your `CallableStatementCallback` will work, as your function doesn't return a result-set, but that hasn't caused a problem yet as your code isn't reaching it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is failing on `error code [17004]; invalid column type: 1111` . This error happens because your code uses a datatype which JDBC doesn't recognise.

This is probably because your function returns BOOLEAN.  Boolean is not a valid SQL datatype. You wouldn't be able to call that a function in a straightforward Oracle SQL query either.

It is true that JDBC does provide [a mapping of `bit` to Java `boolean` and `Boolean`](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~java/docs/guide/jdbc/mapping.doc.html), but that will only work for database products which support that non-standard datatype, and Oracle isn't one of them.